# Video compression in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to compress video before uploading to the server. I am using the react-native-compress library. This library having only compress video function. But this is not working. Is anyone knows other libraries for video compress in react-native?

RNCompress.compressVideo(filePath, quality)

Comment: Did you find any solution? I need a package which will work properly for both platforms

Comment: @David Did you find it?